# iOS Base localization was not used for missing key

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Let's say I have this 2 strings files in my project:

```
Localizable.strings (Base)
"hello_key" = "Hello";
"bye_key" = "Goodbye";
```

and

```
Localizable.strings (Chinese Traditional)
"hello_key" = "您好";
```

And I use the following code to localize the "hello" string

```
NSLocalizedString("hello_key", comment: "")
```

It works fine for "hello_key", but if I use "bye_key" in my iPhone with phone language set to Tradition Chinese, I get "bye_key" as the localized string.

In another word, the Base localization was not used. Is it possible to show the Base English "GoodBye" in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Just add the key `bye_key` to the `Chinese Traditional`.

Comment: @Mozilla yes I can do that, but I am trying to avoid duplicate translation. Because in my project, some words are only needed to be translated once. But if there is no way to achieve what I want, I can translate them in all my localizable.strings files as u said.

Comment: If I'm right undestand, the `bye_key` has only single value in your app. So why do you want use a localized string? Just use a primary value `Goodbye` without Localizable.

Comment: @mozilla you are right. because coming from Android world, for example, facebook login SDK requires us to have a key called "facebook_app_id" in strings.xml file. This kind of key only needs to be "translated" once. But, come to think of it, for iOS, I will just create a static variable in my class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

This is the case of unsupported phrase, because your did not translate completely for Traditional Chinese.

Apple will not fallback to the base language, but simply return the key. This is just how it behaves. I wrote more about it in my [blog](http://samwize.com/2018/01/23/localization-fall-back-to-base-language/).

You have to write a custom `NSLocalizedString` like this (the example uses `en` as the fallback language):

```
public func LS(_ key: String) -> String {
    let value = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
    if value != key || NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first == "en" {
        return value
    }

    // Fall back to en
    guard
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj"),
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
        else { return value }
    return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: bundle, comment: "")
}
```